# Keycloak OpenID Connect and OAuth 2.0 custom authenticator to support multiple Username & Passwords

Tags: oauth-2.0, keycloak, openid-connect

I'm working on a digital vault app and it has a concept called Group Login where multiple members can create a group to store shared assets securely.

In order to login into the vault of this group, at least 2 members of the group should enter their Username/ Passwords on the login screen. Do note that this is a business requirement. For example:

```
On the Login Screen:
--------------------
Member 01: Username
Member 01: Password

Member 02: Username
Member 02: Password

   LOGIN BUTTON
```

This app is just one product in the system and there are other products such as web apps. Considering this, I have decided use Keycloak to manage authentication of users in a single place using OpenID Connect and OAuth 2.

I understand that the above mentioned group login behaviour is not supported by OpenID Connect and OAuth2 in Keycloak. Considering that, I have decided to write a custom authenticator for Keycloak to handle this requirement. But I'm not sure if that's the ideal solution or if it will violate the OpenID Connect and OAuth2 protocols.

My simple question here is: is it acceptable to customize OpenID Connect and OAuth2 to support a scenario like this. If not, what's the ideal approach to handle this?

Comment: This is an interesting scenario, I am curious to know, after you validate the two users, do happen to use their access token's and refresh token in your further flows ? do you validate their roles information which keycloak appends in the access token ? Or is it primarily only to validate the credentials of these users ?

Answer (score 0):

If you treat the group as a [Resource owner](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-1.1) (OAuth2 role), then you are just customizing the authentication mechanism, which is not part of the OAuth2 or OIDC specification. The specification doesn't cover Resource owner sources either, so you can create the group dynamically (as a pair of users). So your concept doesn't violate the protocols.

But you should also make sure that [the userinfo endpoint](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#UserInfo) gives correct info about the group and that [ID tokens](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#IDToken) are generated with correct info about the group.